# Android: importing projects/libraries?

Tags: android, eclipse, github

I am trying to use code from a project that I downloaded from Github, however I am consistently getting errors.

Is there more steps needed to use a project than importing it into eclipse?

I am currently just copying and pasting code from the downloaded project to mine.

**Attempting to use the following:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.mikhaellopez.circularimageviewsample"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:src="@drawable/image"
        app:border="true"
        app:border_color="@color/GrayLight"
        app:border_width="4dp"
        app:shadow="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

But getting the error:

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'border_color' in package 
     'com.mikhaellopez.circularimageviewsample'
    - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'shadow' in package 
     'com.mikhaellopez.circularimageviewsample'
    - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'border' in package 
     'com.mikhaellopez.circularimageviewsample'
    - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'border_width' in package 
     'com.mikhaellopez.circularimageviewsample'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there more steps needed to use a project than importing it into eclipse?

Well, that depends.

> I am currently just copying and pasting code from the downloaded project to mine.

Depending upon how that code is written, that may not work well.

> But getting the error:

Change:

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.mikhaellopez.circularimageviewsample"
```

to:

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

as your app does not have the package name of `com.mikhaellopez.circularimageviewsample`, apparently.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am basically wondering if i need to add certain files to the build path etc?

Comment: @codeme2020: What you are trying to reuse is an Android library project. To reuse one in Eclipse, import it into your workspace, then use Project > Properties > Android in the app project to attach the library to it. https://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#ReferencingLibraryProject For most library projects, that's probably sufficient.

Comment: Worked perfectly thanks, What is the difference between a library project and a regular project? Do you want to write the steps outlined in an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: @codeme2020: "What is the difference between a library project and a regular project?" -- a checkbox in Eclipse. :-) https://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#SettingUpLibraryProject "Do you want to write the steps outlined in an answer so that I can accept it?" -- my answer answers the question that you asked. Everything else has just been commentary follow-up. You had a compile error; I pointed out how to resolve the compile error.

Comment: Is there any reason why the addition of an external library to a project would cause problems within the project? I followed the steps outlined for my project, it caused problems within the project. Would this be because I am already using external APIs. e.g. neurosky?

Comment: @codeme2020: Again, that would depend upon the library and the problems. Adding a library to your project may cause compilation problems, for example, as you discovered in your question. You might wish to ask a fresh Stack Overflow question where you cite the library and the specifics of the problems.