# Adding external library in Eclipse

Tags: android

I'm trying to use this library https://github.com/lopspower/CircularImageView, I added it to my eclipse as shown here http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#ReferencingLibraryProject

When I copy the xml mentioned in the library usage I get this

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'border_color' in package 
     'com.mikhaellopez.circularimageviewsample'
    - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'shadow' in package 
     'com.mikhaellopez.circularimageviewsample'
    - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'border' in package 'com.mikhaellopez.circularimageviewsample'
    - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'border_width' in package 
     'com.mikhaellopez.circularimageviewsample'
```

This is my XML,

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:src="@drawable/image"
        app:border="true"
        app:border_color="@color/GrayLight"
        app:border_width="4dp"
        app:shadow="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try to rebuild and clean the project.

Comment: chage this http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview to xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25232413/android-importing-projects-libraries

Answer (score 1):

Try this as the our xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:src="@drawable/image"
        app:border="true"
        app:border_color="@color/GrayLight"
        app:border_width="4dp"
        app:shadow="true" />
```

Just so you know, I have changed this:

```
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview"
```

to this:

```
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm getting this error,E/AndroidRuntime(12048): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.testcimv-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.testcimv-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]

Comment: are you using eclipse or android studio?

Comment: Yes I'm trying to "Adding external library in Eclipse"